# Drag-down columns in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to drag this formula down to other cells and want to change **B$1:B$1000** to **C$1:C$1000** (and so on...) but when it is dragged down, it just remains the same. **I have read other threads similar to this one** and tried their solutions but with no luck.

```
=INDEX(OFFSET('[1-  Abril  (Captura de datos).xlsx]Moldeo'!B$1:B$1000,COLUMN()-1,0),MATCH($C$1384&$K$1385,'[1-  Abril  (Captura de datos).xlsx]Moldeo'!$A:$A,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've mixed and mismatched the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592). You have put `COLUMN()-1` into the parameter for the *rows*. In fact, you need to put `ROW(1:1)-1` into the *columns* parameter.

```
=INDEX(OFFSET('[1-  Abril  (Captura de datos).xlsx]Moldeo'!B$1:B$1000, 0, ROW(1:1)-1), MATCH($C$1384&$K$1385, '[1-  Abril  (Captura de datos).xlsx]Moldeo'!$A:$A, 1))
```

`ROW(1:1)-1` will progress from *0, 1, 2, 3...* as you fill down. With this in the *columns* parameter, it will offset one column to the right for each row you fill down.

Comment: Works like char, thanks for the correction and solution.

Answer (score 2):

actually **first** you need to drag it to the right and once it is finished, select the outcome cells and copy them and then ***paste special*** and select **transpose**.

Comment: Temporary solution, might be useful in some other problems I might have